# Flask-admin field not shown

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I have simple user-roles models pair, each has `__repr__` method:

```
class User:
    ...........
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User "{}">'.format(self.username)

class Role:
    ...........
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role "{}">'.format(self.rolename)
```

When these models used in Flask-Admin select-box 'Roles' appeared for user, but it is empty because flask-admin renders text unescaped and it is hidden as unknown html tag:

```
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-disabled">
    <div class="select2-result-label">
        <span class="select2-match"></span>
        <role: 'admin'=""></role:></div></li>  ####HERE####
...........
```

How to change text rendering options for models without changing my `__repr___` or `__unicode__` method (I prefer this notation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will disable js page will render right, so look like problem in JS plugin `select2`. I created issue for this in `flask-admin`: https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/issues/244.

Comment: I've take a look on raw HTML without `select2`. It seems that flask-admin missing - it does not suppose any way to render custom text representation.